# Definition of algebraically equivalent

Tags: functions

Long story short, I'm a non-native english speaker, but I'm currently taking mathematic courses in English.
I'm currently studying Linear Systems Theory.

And I have an exercise to do, which requires me to proove that 2 systems are algebraically equivalent.
What does that mean ?
At the moment, my understanding of this notion comes from here :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/properties_of_real_numbers/identifying_equivalent_algebraic_expressions.htm

Where it's less or more written that 2 functions f and g are algrebraically equivalent if :

$$
\forall x \in R, f(x) = g(x)
$$
Yet, for me, that means the 2 functions are equal, the same (provided they are defined on the same sets).

Am I right ? Or is there a difference between "2 functions are the same" and "2 functions are algebraically equivalent".

Because question 5)a) of my exercise is "Are the functions the same ?" and question 5)b) is "Are the functions algebraically equivalent ?".

Thanks for your help.

**#EDIT :**

Here is the full exercise I'm supposed to do :

Consider the following system :
$$
x' = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
x + \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
u,
y= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
x;
$$
$$
x' = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
x + \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
u,
y= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
x;
$$

a) Do the systems have the same transfer function ?

b) Are they algebraically equivalent  ? (this could either refer to the systems or the transfer functions, but maybe it's the same).

Comment: The link you give instead says "equivalent  algebraic expressions."  If the notion of "algebraic ally equivalent systems" comes up in your studies, please provide the context where you find it.

Comment: Without more context I'd guess that "systems are algebraically equivalent" means an isomorphism of (abstract) algebra objects, but you say you are taking a course in Linear Systems Theory.  Perhaps you are studying Linear Algebra, and the systems involved are systems of linear equations?  It is possible that in such a context one is asked to show that two systems of equations are equivalent by [having the same solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#:~:text=Two%20systems%20are%20equivalent%20if,have%20the%20same%20solution%20set.)

Comment: I added more context (meaning the full exercise's statement). As far as I remember, this notion didn't appear anywhere in the course (I may have missed it, but it's unlikely).

Comment: I looked at the link you provided, and this definition seems to make a lot more sense in the current context.

Comment: After reading your exercise, it appears the "systems" you are solving are systems of ordinary differential equations.  I'd guess there is a definition of "algebraically equivalent" in your course materials that you are expected to apply here.